# Using a button with the code inside of a different class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, android-button

I am trying to make an app and I have the code for a button inside of a different class.  When I start my app and click the first button it brings me to a different layout where the button is located.  But when I click this button it doesn't do anything, just the little click down animation.

First Button Code:

```
public class TextAdd extends AppCompatActivity {
public static   EditText Text;
public static   Button Set;
public static   String[] Checkagainst = new String[1000];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.Text_Checker);
    Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LPN);
    Set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Set);

    Set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String Text_Value = Text.getText().toString();
            if (!Arrays.asList(Checkagainst).contains(Text_Value) && Text_Value.length() >= 1 && Text_Value.length() <= 7) {
               setContentView(R.layout.add);


                for (int i = 0; i < Checkagainst.length; i++) {
                    if (Checkagainst[i] == null) {
                        Checkagainst[i] = Text_Value;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            } else if (Arrays.asList(Checkagainst).contains(Text_Value) && Text_Value.length() >= 1 && Text_Value.length() <= 7) {
                setContentView(R.layout.have);

            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

Second Button Code:

```
public class Have extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button HaveBack;
private TextView Have;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.have);
    HaveBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HaveBack);
    Have= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Have);
    String Text_Value= TextAdd.License.getText().toString();
    String Extra = Text_Value + " is already part of Your license plates";
    Have.setText(Extra);
    HaveBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.Text_Checker);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? If so can you please help me.

Comment: No one can possibly know what’s wrong, as you’ve provided no code. This is like ringing a mechanic and saying my car won’t start, please fix it. They’d only be guessing at best. You should provide a [mcve] and we may be able to assist you.

Comment: I changed the question by putting code in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setContentView()` only once in your `onCreate()` method. Calling it multiple times is not correct. If you want to show a small layout above your current layout, you should use a Dialog and if you want to show a completely different layout above everything, you have to use Intents to go to another activity and do the rest of the work in that one.

besides, use lowercase letters at start of your variables' and objects' names and start Class names with Uppercase letters. That's the standard for knowing what is a class and what is an object. e.g.

```
Button firstButton, secondButton;
```

Comment: is that the same if my setcontentviews are in separate classes

Comment: @JohnPaul `setContentView();` should be called only once in each activity to specify a layout file for the activity. so there is no problem in calling it from separate activities.

Comment: Yea.  I believe I am doing that, but correct me if I am wrong.  I am calling a setcontentview in a different class for 2 different layouts.

Comment: Well, I can see that you are calling `setContentView();` once in the beginning of your `TextAdd` Activity and another time in that `onClickListener` which is called on Set. this means by clicking the Set the `SetContentView()` is called twice in your activity. besides I can't see where you have defined `Set` in your scope. I mean if that is a button you should use `setOnClickListener()` on one of it's instances.

Comment: What are instances? Sorry I'm new to android studio.

Comment: For understanding that you should get along with the concepts of OOP (Object Oriented Programming). I recommend you get along with Java first. try taking an online course. you will figure out all of this after that.